# How to can I edit Docker port and args on a container? (using Dockers Desktop for Windows)

Tags: python, docker, pip, anaconda

I creasted a docker container using:

```
    docker run -t -i continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash
```

I've installed all the software, however, I missed out the initial port setup.

When I run the container I can see that I have not setup the port and command line args:

```
    docker container inspect 135c2d60901e
```

I can see what I need to modify to in the JSON it returns but am not able to modify in via Dockers Desktop for windows.  Are there Dockers commands that I should use or do I need to find the location of these files and modify them?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the --publish or -p flag when using docker create or run. The documentation for that is here:

[Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Example:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -t -i continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Does this create a new container or modify the existing?

Comment: It creates a new container.  You should `docker stop; docker rm` the existing container.